# Conditionally remove or add element in document array using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following incoming object from front end:

```
{
 name: "Test 1",
 sets: [1,2]
}
```

**Mongo Schema:** `Sets`

```
name: {
        type: String
      },
tests   : [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref : 'Test'
    }]
```

Let's assume that the document has the following items:

```
[
 {
  name: "Test Set 1",
  tests: [],
  id: 1
 },
 {
  name: "Test Set 2",
  tests: []
  id: 2
 }
]
```

Then using this snippet I try to update the documents but it always removes the last item from the request.

```
const {sets} = req.body;
const {id} = req.params;

const tests = await Set.find({_id: {$in: sets}}).exec();

sets.forEach(async set => {
      tests.forEach(async test => {
        if (set !== test._id) {
         await Set.update({_id: test._id},
           {$addToSet: {tests: id}},
           {upsert: true})
       .exec((err, res) => console.log(err, res, 'ADDTOSET'));
     } 
else {
       await Set.updateMany({tests: {$elemMatch: {$eq: id}}},
          {$pull: {tests: id}}, {multi: true})
       .exec((err, res) => console.log(err, res, 'PULL'));
    }
 });
});
```

How i can update the documents regarding the `sets` array in the `req.body`?

**Example:**

User could select both tests, `1` & `2`, then all `tests` in the `Sets` model should have both.

Then, the user decides to select only `1`, then the `test` with `id` `2` should be removed from the array and so on.

Comment: can you give your desired output?

Comment: sure, `[
 {
  name: "Test Set 1",
  tests: [1],
  id: 1
 },
 {
  name: "Test Set 2",
  tests: [1,2]
  id: 2
 }
]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved it by looping the cursor:**

`id` is coming from the `req.params`, it's the `test` `id`

`sets` array is coming from `req.body`.

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const cursor = Set.find({}).cursor();

for (let set = await cursor.next();
     set != null;
     set = await cursor.next()) 
      {
      if (!set.tests.includes(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)) && !sets.includes(set._id.toString())) {
         await Set.update({_id: set._id}, {$pull: {tests: id}}, {new: true, upsert: true}).exec();
      } else {
         await Set.updateMany({_id:  {$in: sets}}, {$addToSet: {tests: id}}, {new: true}).exec()
      }
}
```